# Trailhead Error : unable to complete the trailhead assignment although all criteria are fulfilled

Tags: salesforce

I am getting the following error while completing the following trail.

> Challenge Not yet complete...
>   Here's what's wrong:
>   The 'Lightning Adoption Dashboard - Lightning' dashboard contains at least one of the components that were required to be removed'

I have done the following steps:

1. Installed the app.
2. Removed all the components except for *All Users*: Using Lightning and # Users That Can't Use Lightning by Profile.

Here is an image of the problem:

[image]

Comment: Show us the screenshot of your current dashboard. It should only have two component in it

Comment: You would get better answers from the folks at https://salesforce.stackexchange.com